# Adding metadata to STM in R

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, corpus, quanteda

I am having trouble with the STM package in R. I have built a corpus in Quanteda and I want to convert it into the STM format. I have saved the metadata as an independent CSV file and I want code that merges the text documents with the metadata. The readCorpus() and the "convert() functions do not automatically add the metadata information to the corpus.

This what it looks like in Quanteda:

```
EUdocvars <- read.csv("EU_metadata.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

EUdocvars$Period <- as.factor(EUdocvars$Period)
EUdocvars$Country <-as.factor(EUdocvars$Country)
EUdocvars$Region <- as.factor(EUdocvars$Region)

EUCorpus <- corpus(textfile(file='PROJECT/*.txt'), encodingFrom = "UTF-8-BOM")
docvars(EUCorpus) <- EUdocvars

EUDfm <- dfm(EUCorpus)
```

Is there a way to do the same thing using the STM package?

Answer (score 2):

Support for this was added just recently (v0.99), after addressing https://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda/issues/209.

So this should work:

```
EUstm <- convert(EUdfm, to = "stm", docvars = docvars(EUCorpus))
```

And then `EUstm` has all of the elements including `meta` that you need for fitting STM models.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one more question. From there, what would be the best way to create an STM model? I ask this because the output is now a TDM, do I some how have to extract this into a format that can be read as: "stm(documents, vocab, K, prevalence)"

Comment: `stm(EUdfm$documents, EUdfm$vocab, K, EUdfm$prevalence)`

Comment: Thank you for responding again! I've tried that but it came up with 

    Error in stm(EUstm$documents, EUstm$vocab, K, EUstm$prevalence) : 
    Word indices are not positive integers

Answer (score 0):

The `stm` object (a list) has an element called `$meta` which takes a dataframe of dimensions `number of documents x number of covariates`. So for your problem:

```
EUCorpus$meta <- EUdocvars
```

Comment: Hey there, Thank you for the response. I am still having problems. Could you tell me how you would go about creating a corpus using my data and meta data that is 'ready' to perform STM using the package. Thank you